# Почему IDEA подчёркивает loadLibrary?

Tags: java

Добрый день, работаю с JNA пытаюсь подключить к проекту .dll библиотеку но IDEA выдаёт ошибку при её подключении то есть подчёркивает loadLibrary

```
ClientW ClientW = (ClientW) java.lang.annotation.Native.loadLibrary("spn", ClientW.class);
```

при на ведение на неё пишет

> Cannot resolve method 'loadLibrary(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class Client.class)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Документация по java.lang.annotation.Native](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Native.html)

Где вы там нашли метод loadLibrary?

UPD:

Код из примера:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
...
    MyLib lib = (MyLib) Native.loadLibrary("my", MyLib.class);
```

Ваш код:

```
java.lang.annotation.Native.loadLibrary("spn", ClientW.class);
```

Найдите 3 различия. Подсказка, `com.sun.jna.Native != java.lang.annotation.Native`

Comment: Не понял вопроса ? Так пишет студия если про подключение так показано в примерах.

Comment: @VargSieg я не знаю, откуда вы берете примеры, но `java.lang.annotation.Native` - это даже не класс, а аннотация и методов у нее нет в принципе. Пройдите по ссылке на документацию и внимательно прочитайте. После просветления, чисто для интереса, дополните вопрос примером, которому пытаетесь следовать - может вы просто неправильно его поняли.

Comment: Вот пример https://habrahabr.ru/post/113436/ и вот ещё один http://ru.intechcore.com/jna-for-access-to-native-com-dll-library/

Comment: @VargSieg Дополнил ответ

Comment: Вы правы я на это внимания не обратил, но почему тогда IDEA упорото не хочет менять java.lang.annotation.Native на com.sun.jna.Native библиотека подключена но при попытке импортировать  com.sun.jna меняет на  java.lang.annotation ?

Comment: @VargSieg может идея глючит, может библиотеку вы подключили некорректно. Тут уже разбираться надо. Попробуйте принудительно написать `com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary("spn", ClientW.class);`, если будет продолжать ругаться, то смотрите в сторону подключения библиотеки, скорее всего проблемы там.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52433/discussion-between-varg-sieg-and-rjhdby).